# How can I search through a 2D array to make sure that the there are not more than 3 consecutive chars?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array of 3 random chars, a, b, and c.  I need to make sure that no column or row has three or more repeating chars. 
I'm not really sure how to check the arrays. I think I need to use a loop to go through the array but I'm not sure how to check if there are repeats. To clarify,

**if a column has three A's in a row that would not be allowed or could 3 B's be in a column, etc.**
So if it is like AAA in 3 consecutive array index (in terms of rows and columns), it should stop.

Comment: what have you tried? Is this homework? If it is: are you aware that you're legally obliged to cite StackOverflow if you use a solution from here somewhere else?

Comment: Yes it is homework.  I'm trying to figure out how to

Comment: You are right about the loop. And 3 chars means you should check one char at left and one char at right of the current char, also upper and lower for column. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use for loops if you know the indexes of your array.

so lets say:

```
char[][] arr= new char[20][20];

for(int i=0; i<18;i++){
  for(int j=0; j<18;j++){
   if( arr[i][j] ==arr[i][j+1] && arr[i][j] == arr[i][j+2]))
     {
      break;//mark it as Duplicate
      }
   else if (arr[i][j] == arr[i+1][j] && arr[i][j] == arr[i+2][j])
      {
      break;//mark it as Duplicate
      }
   else
     continue;
   }
 }
```

So basically you are traversing the array and comparing 3 consecutive elements together. if they are equal it breaks.

Comment: Nice answer. I hope OP follows SO's terms and your license, which requires that OP links to this answer and says that the "nested loop approach was done by Manik Singh" or anything like that.

Comment: `char[][] arr= new char[20][20];` What is this?

Comment: oops sorry i coded in java, in c++ we can declare 2D array by:

char arr[20][20];

Answer (score 0):

You can use an automaton.  One to recognize sequences of `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` is:

```
state   input   next   stop
=====   =====   ====   ====
0       A       a1     no
0       B       b1     no
0       C       c1     no
a1      A       a2     no
a1      B       b1     no
a1      C       c1     no
b1      A       a1     no
b1      B       b2     no
b1      C       c1     no
c1      A       a1     no
c1      B       b1     no
c1      C       c2     no
a2      A       3      yes
a2      B       b1     no
a2      C       c1     no
b2      A       a1     no
b2      B       3      yes
b2      C       c1     no
c2      A       a1     no
c2      B       b1     no
c2      C       3      yes
3       A       3      yes
3       B       3      yes
3       C       3      yes
```

you can run this automaton for each row and for each column and stop as soon as you get output `yes` (it has detected three consecutive letters)  You'll get stopped as soon as you recognize the first occurrence of three consecutive letters with only two passes (one for the rows, other for the columns) through the matrix.  Of course, initial state is `0`.